# Chrome not default browser for certain operations

Tags: windows, google-chrome

According to the Chrome settings page, Chrome is currently set as my default browser. However, while some operations (such as clicking on a URL in a non-browser application) do launch Chrome, others (such as the command `start <URL>` in a command prompt) launch IE. How can I ensure that Chrome is the default browser for *all* operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Chrome's check for whether or not it is the default browser is not very robust. Making another browser (such as IE) the default, then making Chrome the default again, appears to fix most of these issues.

Note that this will *only* affect web-browsing defaults. Chrome is capable of handling various extensions and protocols (such as `MAILTO`) that do not have to do with web browsing. (I suspect that the exact list of protocols Chrome can handle may depend on which apps and/or extensions you have installed.) You can choose exactly which associations to make with Chrome via the "Set your default programs" Start menu entry (which launches `Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Set Default Programs`).